# Is one column being part of multiple composite FK constraints valid and good design decision?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

Is it alright to have one column in a table part of two composite FK constraints?

Say we have multiple branches of our business, and we have two different entities, each belonging to a specific branch.

Now we want to associate those two entities (many-to-many), but only allow association if they belong to the same branch.

So we would have three tables:

- EntityA
- EntityB
- Entities

The way I see it, I have couple of options:

1) Use surrogate key for all PKs

- EntityA (`entitya_id` (pk), `branch_id` (fk), other columns)
- EntityB (`entityb_id` (pk), `branch_id` (fk), other columns)
- Entities (`entities_id` (pk), `entitya_id` (fk), `entityb_id` (fk))

The problem with this one is I need `SELECT` statements inside a trigger to do validation. I'd rather not do that. Also, `SELECT` statements become more complex as it will often require `JOIN`s to access some information.

2) Use natural composite keys

- EntityA (PK: `entitya_id`, `branch_id`)
- EntityB (PK: `entityb_id`, `branch_id`)
- Entities (PK `entitya_id`, `entitya_branch_id`, `entityb_id`, `entityb_branch_id`)

This too requires validation in a trigger, but at least I need just simple `IF` comparison of `NEW` values. On the other hand, number of keys/columns grows rapidly, and even in simple cases table can have huge composite keys with a lot of redundant data.

3) Also use natural composite keys, but have only one column reference two tables

This was my first choice, but I thought it's not allowed to have one column reference keys in multiple tables. While you can't do it with only one column, apparently it is allowed to have that column be part of multiple composite constraints, which is demonstrated [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8smHfKq3JXT18moeQEhDLQ/0)

- EntityA (PK: `entitya_id`, `branch_id`)
- EntityB (PK: `entityb_id`, `branch_id`)
- Entities (PK: `entitya_id`, `entityb_id`, `branch_id`)

With the FK defined as following:

```sql
CONSTRAINT `entities_entitya`
    FOREIGN KEY (`entitya_id`, `branch_id`)
    REFERENCES `entitya` (`entitya_id`, `branch_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT `entities_entityb`
    FOREIGN KEY (`entityb_id`, `branch_id`)
    REFERENCES `entityb` (`entityb_id`, `branch_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

So `branch_id` becomes some sort of shared FK

So to repeat my question:

- is this legit thing to do?
- Does it violate some norms?
- Is this going to blow up in my face somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your solution #3, and I think it's a clever solution to your validation requirement. It models the real-world requirement accurately — that both entities must belong to the same branch.

I don't see how it will cause any problems, unless hypothetically the requirement evolves later. For example, you might get a slightly different requirement that the two branches may be different, as long as they're affiliated with each other somehow.

In that case, you'd need two different columns, but then you'd also use each branch column in two different foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Entities (
  entitya_id        INT,
  entitya_branch_id INT,
  entityb_id        INT,
  entityb_branch_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (entitya_id, entitya_branch_id) 
    REFERENCES entitya(entitya_id, branch_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (entityb_id, entityb_branch_id) 
    REFERENCES entitya(entityb_id, branch_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (entitya_branch_id, entityb_branch_id) 
    REFERENCES EntityAffiliations(entitya_branch_id, entityb_branch_id)
)
```

Comment: As if I asked a question about nuclear physics and got an answer from Robert Oppenheimer himself :) Good enough for me to be accepted immediately.
Thanks Bill, I'm very happy to see you're back on SO. I'm sure a lot of people are grateful for having someone like you take their time to help the community.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the praise. I'm glad to help.